# How can I recognize the elements to which is attached some jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

```
$("#s").on("click")
```

This kind of code is very nice, easy and intuitive, but looking on a website that we don't know a developer see only something changing without knowing the reason.. it's possible to use DOM Breakpoints but otherwise seems to be impossible to realize why an element has changed.

How can we find the piece of code like the one at the top which is producing this effect? How to break the JS code execution when a jQuery event is launched?

Comment: Can you explain the downvote?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool, other than the browser's developer tools, to help with this?

Comment: @j08691: I'm looking for everything that can help. Methodology, piece of code, jquery extensions, tools, way of thinking, everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi?hl=en). It shows exactly what jQuery code is attached to an object.